# only load iframe when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, href

How can I display one iframe at a time? So I have an index webpage that has links in the nav to the iframes but I want the iframes to only display when the links are clicked? Right now they are both displaying.Is this a javascript solution? I am new to coding so if so then it might just be easier for me to not use iframes and just set up different pages and target an id.

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/r2mmb/

HTML

```
 <header>
<div id="logo">
<img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="iframetoursprices.html" target="toursprices">
    TOURS,PRICES &amp; STANDARD FLIGHTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MEET THE STAFF</a></li>
<li><a href="iframegallery.html" target="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
    </header>

 <div class="mainInfo">
<iframe src="iframetoursprices.html" name="toursprices"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframegallery.html" name="gallery"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you you don’t just use _one_ iframe, and then use the links with target attribute to load either the one or the other page into that …?

Comment: Which do you actually want: (A) Only one is loaded or (B) Only display one?

Comment: @CBroe hi yes that could work just never thought of it. would you be able to demonstrate in a fiddle please?

Comment: I would like to display one page at a time within an iframe that will display when the link is clicked

Comment: No, I won’t “demonstrate” stuff that is most trivial …

Comment: @CBroe I have added one iframe like your suggestion but am not sure how I would be able to make it scroll down when clicked to the actual iframe which is a bit further down the page?

Answer (score 2):

One approach I'd suggest is first hiding all the `<iframe>` elements with CSS:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

And creating a CSS rule, using a `class`, to show that element:

```
iframe.inUse {
    display: block;
}
```

With the jQuery:

```
// binds a click handler to all 'a' elements with a 'target' attribute:
$('a[target]').click(function(){
    // creates a reference to the clicked-link:
    var clickedEl = this;

    // gets all 'iframe' elements in the document:
    $('iframe')
        // removes the 'inUse' class from all of them:
        .removeClass('inUse')
        // filters the collection of 'iframe' elements:
        .filter(function(){
            // we keep only the 'iframe' whose 'name' attribute
            // is equal to the 'name' attribute of the clicked 'a':
            return this.name === clickedEl.target;
        // and we add the 'inUse' class to that iframe element:
        }).addClass('inUse');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r2mmb/3/).

An alternative is to have only one `<iframe>` element on the page, hide it with the CSS:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

And load the content into that single `<iframe>` with the following jQuery:

```
$('a[target]').click(function(e){
    // prevents the default click-behaviour of the link:
    e.preventDefault();

    // finds the 'iframe' element with the name of 'showContent':
    $('iframe[name="showContent"]')
        // sets its 'src' property equal to the 'href' property of the clicked link:
        .prop('src', this.href)
        // shows the 'iframe':
        .show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r2mmb/4/).

A belated edit, to use plain JavaScript, made upon the somewhat overdue explanation that jQuery cannot be used:

```
function contentToIframe () {
    // getting a reference to the 'iframe' element whose 'name' attribute
    // is equal to the clicked element's 'target' attribute, using CSS
    // notation available under document.querySelector() (which returns
    // only the first element that matches the selector):
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[name="' + this.target + '"]'),
        // getting a reference to the current 'display' (inline) style of
        // the 'iframe' (found above):
        curDisplay = iframe.style.display;

    // setting the 'src' property of the 'iframe' equal to the 'href'
    // of the clicked link:
    iframe.src = this.href;

    // if the 'iframe' doesn't have a set 'display' style-property, or
    // it is not set to 'block':
    if (!curDisplay || curDisplay !== 'block') {
        // we set it to 'block' to make it visible:
        iframe.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

// getting all the 'a' elements in the document that also have a 'target'
// attribute:
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[target]');

// iterating over those link elements:
for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    // binding an event-handler to deal with the click event,
    // which executes the function:
    links[i].addEventListener('click', contentToIframe);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r2mmb/5/).

Final iteration of the above (still plain JavaScript) approach which now also allows for scrolling to the `<iframe>` when the link is clicked to load content:

```
function contentToIframe() {
    var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[name="' + this.target + '"]'),
        curDisplay = iframe.style.display,
        // getting a reference to the current position of the 'iframe' element:
        position = iframe.getBoundingClientRect();
    iframe.src = this.href;
    if (!curDisplay || curDisplay !== 'block') {
        iframe.style.display = 'block';
        // if the 'iframe' wasn't visible it's position would have been 0,0;
        // so once we've made it visible we re-get its new (now visible)
        // coordinates:
        position = iframe.getBoundingClientRect();
    }

    // force the window to scrollTo the current position (x,y) of the 'iframe':
    window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);
}

var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[target]');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', contentToIframe);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/r2mmb/6/).

References:

- 'Plain' JavaScript:

  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
  - [`Window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo).
- jQuery (used before the OP decided to share his *inability to use jQuery*)

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [Has-attribute (`[attribute]`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: Is this jquery or javascript? Sorry I don't know much so I can't tell. In my assignment I am not allowed to use jquery only javascript :/

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript, it's simply a library that abstracts away some of the complexity of native JavaScript for cross-browser use. This answer does, however, rely upon jQuery, yes. I have tried to explain the code in my most-recent edit, to explain what it's doing.

Comment: Wait: you *can't use jQuery?* Can I ask why you've used the [tag:jquery] in your question, without referencing the fact that it cannot be used? The tags to a question should show the languages that *are* or *may be* used, not those that are unavailable to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the class `.active` to the iframe that you combiene

and adds the onclick event to your menu.

look at this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/r2mmb/1/