# how to link to an id and an iframe inside it?

Tags: html, iframe

I have one iframe on my index page that I want to have links to different pages. But I also want the link when clicked to navigate down to the actual frame, as right now it is just staying at the top of the page. I am quite confused about this.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <header>
<div id="logo">
<img src="../../assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="iframetoursprices.html" target="">TOURS,PRICES &amp; STANDARD  FLIGHTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MEET THE STAFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="iframegallery.html" target="iframe">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```
 <div id="mainInfo">
 <iframe src="about:blank" name="iframe"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: Have you used javascript window.scrollTo(x, y)? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo

Comment: Assuming this is related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23330696/), you'll see that functionality was added [in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330696/only-load-iframe-when-link-is-clicked/23330779#23330779). Though admittedly you never *asked* that question (and only referred to it in comments).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking of anchored links:

```
<li><a href="iframegallery.html#iframe">Gallery</a></li>
```

And iframegallery.html:

```
<div id="mainInfo">
<iframe src="about:blank" name="iframe" id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>
```